# Cloudant/couchdb document can't be deleted due to 409 conflict

Tags: couchdb, cloudant, ibm-cloud

I have a Java application running in IBM Bluemix that is using a Cloudant (couchdb) database as a service.  I have a document in that database which can't be deleted, as Cloudant returns a 409 conflict error when I try.  However, when I query it for conflicts, it doesn't report any:

```
$ curl 'https://<user>-bluemix:<pass>@<host>-bluemix.cloudant.com/<dbname>/e4eca7af-cb27-4b1e-b738-31abcf880680?conflicts=true' 
{
"_id": "e4eca7af-cb27-4b1e-b738-31abcf880680", 
"_rev": "13887-a24ecaf2f6e628903e294b11e73d8ca8", 
...[other stuff but no _conflicts section]
}
```

And when I try to delete it:

```
$ curl -i -X DELETE 'https://<user>-bluemix:<pass>@<host>-bluemix.cloudant.com/<dbname>/e4eca7af-cb27-4b1e-b738-31abcf880680?_rev=13887-a24ecaf2f6e628903e294b11e73d8ca8'
HTTP/1.1 409 Conflict
X-Couch-Request-ID: 02286a98ac
Server: CouchDB/1.0.2 (Erlang OTP/R14B)
Date: Wed, 15 Apr 2015 12:35:00 GMT
Content-Type: text/plain;charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 58
Cache-Control: must-revalidate
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff;

{"error":"conflict","reason":"Document update conflict."}
```

This is a document that has been deleted and recreated many times (which is how the _rev count got so high). Normally it works fine, but every now and then it gets into this conflict state. I have found that I can delete it through the Cloudant web interface, but seemingly not through the REST interface. But once I delete it, it works fine for a while and then the problem comes back.

So why does it say there's a conflict when I try to delete, but it won't tell me what the conflict is with the 'conflicts=true' parameter? I have also tried '_deleted_conflicts=true' and this also shows nothing.

How did it get into this state, and how can I prevent it happening in the future?

Comment: Looping in our cloudant folks...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to say `?rev=`, not `?_rev=` to pass the revision correctly.

http://docs.couchdb.org/en/1.6.1/api/document/common.html#delete--db-docid

Comment: Thanks, that's embarrassing.  :-)  However that problem was only with my manual testing in curl-- the actual code was always correctly using 'rev' not '_rev'.  So there was still some sort of intermittent problem where the document was not originally deleted.  I'm accepting this answer since it addressed my immediate issue, I'll see if the problem comes back.

Comment: Worth mentioning that you can also use the `If-Match` HTTP header. Since that is a standard header, there is less of a chance of misspelling it.

Answer (score 2):

When you are deleting a document in Cloudant, you must supply the revision token as a "rev" parameter. You are passing in a "_rev" parameter. The error you are seeing is as if you haven't passed the revision at all.

See

https://docs.cloudant.com/api.html#delete36

Answer (score 1):

Talked with our cloudant support folks, its actually `rev=` not `_rev=`.